# Select two duplicate records if it has 3 duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get only two duplicate records in SQL Server if it has three duplicate records? Example I have records '10/13/2020', '10/13/2020, '10/13/2020'. as you can see, it has 3 duplicate records. What I want is I will select only two duplicate records. if it has count 4, and 5 and above, still 2 counts will get

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT [Date] Count(*)
    FROM tablename
    WHERE [Date] = '10/13/2020'
    GROUP BY [Date]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Current output:

```
Date                      Count
2020-10-13 00:00:00.000   3
```

I want only to retrieve two counts, is that possible?

Comment: `Count(*)-1`? What are you trying to achieve? I think you are missing a comma between `[Date]` and `count(*)`. And whats with the 'IF EXISTS'?

Comment: I think `10/013/2020' should be `10/13/2020'. Also, you should avoid reserved keyword name as column name like `Date`.

Comment: Hi sir @SurajKumar thats why i used "[]"

Comment: Hi @DaleK im trying to achieve is that even it if has more than 3 duplicate, i still want to get 2 duplicate only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this using the window functions

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select [date]
      ,RN  = row_number() over (partition by date order by date)
      ,Cnt = sum(1) over (partition by date)
 From  YourTable
)
Select *
 From  cte
 Where RN<=2 and Cnt>=3
```